# <jsp:param> throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, jsp, nullpointerexception, weblogic, jsp-tags

I am getting NullPointerException in Weblogic Server while changing below changes in jsp:

```
    <jsp:include page="Nav.jspx">
        <jsp:param name="invoiceType" value="${invoiceTypeLong}"/>
        <jsp:param name="current" value="Header"/>
    </jsp:include>
```

I have given instructions to modify above code to below mentioned code for security implementations.Both code snippents are working fine in tomcat but coming to weblogic below mentioned code giving NullPointerException.

```
   <jsp:include page="Nav.jspx">
        <jsp:param name="invoiceType"> 
            <jsp:attribute name="value"> 
               <c:out value="${invoiceTypeLong}"/> 
            </jsp:attribute> 
         </jsp:param>
        <jsp:param name="current" value="Header"/>
    </jsp:include>
```

Could anybody suggest me if i required to change any configuration files or what is the cause?

**Exception StackTrace:**

```
2014-07-21 05:13:38.861 0       Error   Exception          weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP /WEB-INF/ml/jsp/Invoice/INVOICE/Header.jspx
 Exception occurred while processing 'C:\Views\spambi_64view\GC3\WEB-INF\ml\jsp\Invoice\INVOICE\Header.jspx'java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.JspScriptTransform$TransformContext.addTokens(JspScriptTransform.java:2408)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.JspJavaTransform.addParamTag(JspJavaTransform.java:1100)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.JspJavaTransform.addActionBefore(JspJavaTransform.java:171)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.JspScriptTransform.transformAction(JspScriptTransform.java:1194)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.JspScriptTransform.transformAll(JspScriptTransform.java:750)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.JspScriptTransform.transformAction(JspScriptTransform.java:1207)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.JspScriptTransform.transformAll(JspScriptTransform.java:750)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.JspScriptTransform.transformAction(JspScriptTransform.java:1425)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.JspScriptTransform.transformAll(JspScriptTransform.java:750)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.JspScriptTransform.transformAction(JspScriptTransform.java:1122)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.JspScriptTransform.transformAll(JspScriptTransform.java:750)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.JspScriptTransform.addJspService(JspScriptTransform.java:221)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.JspScriptTransform.transformPage(JspScriptTransform.java:178)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.JspScriptTransform.<init>(JspScriptTransform.java:153)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.JspCheckContext.check(JspCheckContext.java:82)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.JspAnalyzer.check(JspAnalyzer.java:57)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.ProxySourceFile._check(ProxySourceFile.java:140)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.SourceFile.masterCheck(SourceFile.java:782)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.SourceFile.check(SourceFile.java:314)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.SourceFile.check(SourceFile.java:335)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.ProxySourceFile.codeGen(ProxySourceFile.java:229)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.SourceFile.codeGen(SourceFile.java:327)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.client.ClientUtilsImpl$CodeGenJob.run(ClientUtilsImpl.java:622)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.client.Job.performJob(Job.java:85)
    at weblogic.jsp.internal.client.ThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPool.java:219)
Header.jspx: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Your syntax is definitely incorrect. Reference this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780314/why-jspinclude-parameters-not-visible

Comment: I didn't find any syntax error here. as it is working fine in tomcat server. No issue faced here but once we migrated to weblogic server it is throwing NullPointerException.